# How to get a page title

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

i need to get the page name of a google sites with google apps script, there is another post about it but is about URL such as [Retrieve page title from URL in Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284285/retrieve-page-title-from-url-in-apps-script), but i need to get the page title name.

Thanks.

Comment: That article you refer to actually says that you want to parse the html:

"If you want to get the title of the page at a 'normal' URL, then you can get the contents of the page using UrlFetchApp.fetch(url) and then parse the title tag."

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a domain, use the following, replacing teh strings as appropriate.

```
var site = SitesApp.getSite("mydomainname.org", "sitename");
var page = site.getChildren()[0];
var title = page.getTitle();
```

Karl

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70765338/1176573) stackoverflow answer, the function works well for getting page title.

```
function betweenMarkers(text, begin, end) {
  var firstChar = text.indexOf(begin) + begin.length;
  var lastChar = text.indexOf(end);
  var newText = text.substring(firstChar, lastChar);
  return newText;
}

var pageTitle = betweenMarkers(response.getContentText(),"<title>","</title>")
console.log(pageTitle)
```